# Java won't compile on Ubuntu but compiles on Windows

Tags: java

I have a problem. On my windows desktop, I run a java file without any errors. I run it with java sdk version: 15.0.2. Now I have that same file that I want to run on my ubuntu machine, but when I try:
`javac Test.java`, it gives me the following errors:

```
Test.java:16: error: illegal start of expression
        return switch (unit) {
               ^
Test.java:17: error: : expected
            case "m" -> 60L * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                    ^
Test.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
            case "m" -> 60L * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                     ^
Test.java:18: error: : expected
            case "h" -> 60L * 60 * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                    ^
Test.java:18: error: illegal start of expression
            case "h" -> 60L * 60 * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                     ^
Test.java:19: error: : expected
            case "d" -> 60L * 60 * 24 * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                    ^
Test.java:19: error: illegal start of expression
            case "d" -> 60L * 60 * 24 * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                     ^
Test.java:20: error: : expected
            default -> 0;
                   ^
Test.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
            default -> 0;
                    ^
9 errors
```

Here is the full code of `Test.java`:

```
package com.company.drivers;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(getPeriodMultiplierSecs("15m"));
        
    }


    public static long getPeriodMultiplierSecs(String period) {
        String quantity = period.substring(0, period.length() - 1);
        String unit = period.substring(period.length() - 1);

        return switch (unit) {
            case "m" -> 60L * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
            case "h" -> 60L * 60 * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
            case "d" -> 60L * 60 * 24 * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
            default -> 0;
        };
    }
}
```

The java ubuntu version is `11.0.10`.
Why am I getting these errors on ubuntu and how can I fix that?

Comment: Can you first sync java versions pls in both the os?

Comment: Because that syntax won't work with java 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the switch-as-expression language feature, which was introduced in java 12. Thus, this code cannot be compiled on java11 or below.

Ubuntu vs. Windows is a complete red herring; `javac` is the exact same thing on all platforms. It's about 11 v 15.

Upgrade to 15. Alternatively, rewrite that switch to a statement based variant which has been part of java since java 1 (though, switching on strings is a java6-ism. Still, that's over a decade old so no worries about compatibility there):

```
int v;
switch (unit) {
case "m":
    v = 60L * Integer.parseInt(quantity);
    break;
case "h": .... and so on.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will upgrade my java!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the `java -version` and not Windows vs. Ubuntu.

The arrow syntax shown in your `switch` statement was not introduced until Java 12. https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-12-switch-statementsexpressions-in-action:

> As stated previously, we can use the new "arrow" syntax ("switch labeled rules") with the enhancedswitch statement. This is shown in the next code example that compiles and runs against the JDK 12 Early Access Build 10 when --enalved-preview is used.

You should *do one of*:

- upgrade Java on your Ubuntu system to at least version 12
- change your `case` statements to not use the arrow operator and use the traditional colon style